# Error connecting to Windows Terminal Server VIA network boot

Tags: boot, networking, rdp, ltsp

I am currently trying to load a windows terminal server screen instead of a Ubuntu screen , I keep receiving a blank black screen with only the cursor visible or an error screen with a lengthy busybox v.1.85 error which I am not sure of.

I created a file in pathway ; -

pico /var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/amd64/lts.conf

within here I then added the following ; -

[DEFAULT]

SCREEN07 = rdesktop
RDP_SERVER = "192.168.???.??"

I have configured the DHCP server etc and test machines but the only part I am stuck on is loading the actual IP address I inputted into the file above to run at network boot.

Can anyone also explain what SCREEN07 represents.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XX in SCREEN_XX is the session number. You switch beetwen sessions with keyboard shortcut: Ctrl+Alt+F01 (or F02 etc). You can have multiple SCREENs configured and switch at client without interrupting other sessions. Usually RDP session is set SCREEN_07, but it's not mandatory.

As of **rdesktop**. I don't have much experience with it, but I'm more familiar with Freerdp which is in fact a fork of rdesktop. So some troubleshooting steps might apply to both of them.

In Freerdp a blank screen might happen when the security of session is not properly defined.

**First:** if the RDP server doesn't have it's own certificate issued by Certificate Authority , RDP client should ignore it.

**Second:** setting authentication type is crucial. Usually disabling Network Level Authentication is the simplest solution.

So your config should look like this:

```
# xfreerdp's OLD style syntax
[DEFAULT]
SCREEN_07=xfreerdp
RDP_SERVER=192.168.X.X
RDP_OPTIONS="-f --no-nla --ignore-certificate"
```

OR

```
# xfreerdp's NEW style syntax
[DEFAULT]
SCREEN_07=xfreerdp
RDP_SERVER=192.168.X.X
RDP_OPTIONS="/f /sec:rdp /cert-ignore"
```

Check rdesktop manual and use it's options analogously.

Comment: thanks for your help this has been very useful , do you have a sure fire way off installing freerdp as i am having extreme difficulty in installing the application.